# Asp.Net httphandler cause 500 (Internal server error)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, handler, httphandler, internal-server-error

I want to add a handler to my existing web form application.

Following this [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx) in web.config I've added:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="post" path="redirect.ashx" type="RedirectHandler"/> 
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I've created a Generic Handler (called RedirectHandler.ashx) in App_Code folder,
but when I run the application (VS2017) it causes a 500.

The tutorial makes a distinction between registering in IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0. I'm not sure which one applies to me considering that VS runs IIS Express 10.0. Anyway, I've already tried both with poor results.

I'm a noobie to web forms but it seems pretty straightforward. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

EDIT: Creating a new project and adding httphandlers doesn't cause any issue. So it must be some configuration with my current project but I have no idea what may cause the error.

EDIT 2: To answer at the 500 error, the problem was caused by the wrong "type" in httpHandlers. Type should be "Namespace.class".

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573247/how-do-i-restrict-post-access-to-a-httphandler) really helped me to figure out a few things.

Comment: Why you have added `RedirectHandler.ashx` in `App_Code` folder? Try moving it out of `App_Code` folder. And since it is a generic there is no need to register it inside web.config. You can `POST` data to your handler using `http://{yourdomain}/redirect.ashx` (assuming that redirect.ashx is located at website root)

Comment: @MohsinMehmood thanks. I'm realizing now that I need to register Httphandlers only for custom extensions.